# Is there a tool for making secure cold wallets?

Tags: cold-storage

There is a [quite long and complex guide](https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/comments/48cgmd/an_extensive_guide_for_securely_generating_an/) on how to make a secure 'cold' or offline wallet on reddit. Is there a quicker and more simple way to do this that takes less time and is less complicated, but still just as secure?

Answer (score 19):

Funny you should ask, Taushet, because indeed there is!

The [Taushet USB Monero Cold Wallet Generator](https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/comments/5limu9/taushet_usb_monero_cold_wallet_generator_release/) is a pre-packaged, pre-hashed and pre-zipped collection of the tools required to make a secure wallet that only requires a single checking/security hash. It takes around 10 minutes to make a secure cold wallet. The tool has been hashed and verified by many community members ([see here](https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/comments/55dhkf/taushet_usb_monero_cold_wallet_generator/)).

The full instructions can be found on the [reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/comments/55dhkf/taushet_usb_monero_cold_wallet_generator/), but here is the meat of it:

What you need:

- 1 x taushet-USB-wallet-gen.zip
- 3 x USB thumbdrives
- 1 x paper
- 1 x pen
- 1 x Hash utility ()

How to use:

1. Download the zip from the link on the reddit post (pgp signed)
2. Physically disconnect from the internet.
3. Check that the hash of the file matches those on the reddit post.
4. Extract the zip file, which contains: slacko64-6.3.0.iso, Rufus-2.11.exe, monero-wallet-generator-master (dir), and this ReadMe.txt.
5. Make a bootable USB of the ISO using Rufus 2.11. Agree to all the default settings in the dialog boxes.
6. Drag the monero-wallet-generator-master directory to the USB drive.
7. Reboot using the USB into PuppyLinux (hold down F12 during boot to select boot drive)
8. Open the monero-wallet-generator.html file in the directory, generate the wallet seed and keys
9. Save the seed, address and keys to the *second* USB drive. Copy/paste, don't type. This is you digital vault, not to be used until fund extraction.
10. Write down the seed three times on a single sheet of paper. This is your physical vault.
11. Save the address (and maybe viewkey) to the *third* USB drive. This is your address usb, which can be used with relative abandon.
12. Remove *second* and *third* USB drives.
13. Wipe the *first* USB drive (containing the wallet generator and linux), or destroy it.
14. Remove all USB drives.
15. Reboot, reconnect internet.

You now have a cold wallet!

Comment: Note that **Ledger is currently (March 2018) working on supporting Monero $XMR**. The implementation is well on its way, so hopefully it'll be **live by end of Q2 2018**. You can follow the progress on by looking at the relevant ticket on **Ledger's public Trello board** https://trello.com/c/wsK0myEm/52-monero-support - if you want more info, the best place to find answers is directly in the Reddit threads mentioned in the ticket description.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another variant - entirely DIY for Windows users, using `monero-wallet-cli` and generating a watch-wallet at the end of the process.

[How to create a cold storage & watch-only wallet](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/3060/how-to-create-a-cold-storage-watch-only-wallet)

Note: missing hash-checking

Comment: The method discussed in this answer is better insofar as it involves the creation of watch-keys, which allow the owner to watch outgoing transactions (rather than just incoming, as with a normal viewkey). It is, however, far more complex.

Answer (score 1):

Check this offline generator in Monero website https://moneroaddress.org/#gpg-instructions

Answer (score 1):

I made an offline command-line tool, [subaddress-derive-xmr](https://github.com/dan-da/subaddress-derive-xmr), that can do this.

Usage would look like:

```
$ ./subaddress-derive-xmr --gen-wallet  -g
{
    "seed": "66dcbb7490ee34dad1b04fa316b90ba1795ce70586298e2cc09455de1ae95273",
    "mnemonic": "focus aquarium luxury etched video smidgen sidekick because rounded cigar befit ritual layout visited wetsuit tobacco oars setup mystery insult females dauntless yodel jeopardy rounded",
    "wordset": "english",
    "view-key-private": "25d014a444fb7a1e6836c680d3ec1b6eed628a29c3c85e0379fb89f53c4c610a",
    "view-key-public": "603ebe3bc1b2590c8a5e4caa90ee807cada4f881ad4f21f6c3653459781034c0",
    "spend-key-private": "eb1003ead738b471f5668a2e00e4f20e795ce70586298e2cc09455de1ae95203",
    "spend-key-public": "dce90ff7304d8b648bfbac69624b4c6562340c5c748a8a6d2c84bad3b76fe974",
    "address": "49zf2PF7nLSHpRwWcPG8ePHxYnR6eFmYuKG8Akpq5vFALTzZzMdv3kC36fCSP3UfFdMrY51QAs5NGiGuwXK6YMa3Nk7549x"
}
```

Any number of subaddresses can also be easily derived if needed.  See usage docs.