# How can I put my Aeon in Cold Storage?

Tags: cold-storage, aeon

Has a tutorial been made for putting Aeon in cold storage?

Answer (score 6):

There is an offline wallet generator for Aeon here: https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=641696.msg17660358#msg17660358

This is the same as the Monero one, but adapted for Aeon. The post above says it's new and you should make sure you can restore your address before trusting an address/keys set made with the generator, just in case, but the Monero version has been working well.

Answer (score 4):

Same principles apply as for Monero or any other coin for that matter - generate a wallet offline and never expose it to an online computer.

You could do this by using Aeon wallet software, similar to what has been described [here](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/3060/how-to-create-a-cold-storage-watch-only-wallet). The guide is for Windows, but you could do the same by booting off some Linux live-CD as well, and running the Linux binaries on it.

Write down your seed mnemonic, private keys and address and store securely.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative Aeon offline wallet generator was created by JollyMort that employs 98 **dice rolls for entropy**, rather than the computer system's PRNG: https://jollymort.github.io/monero-wallet-generator/monero-wallet-generator-d6.html. Click on the green drop-down button that says <kbd>MONERO</kbd> and choose <kbd>AEON</kbd> instead.

Comment: For the record, the original allows custom entropy instead of the computer's PRNG.