# Is my hot wallet the only view wallet and my cold wallet the one created offline?

Tags: cold-storage, hot-wallet

I am a little confuse and concern about my wallet security. I've created a wallet using moneroaddress.org, I went offline and generated a new wallet I saved all my keys and erased my browser history, then I went online again. I created a monero view-only wallet using the CLI by inputing the previous generated Public Address and View Key and synced it using a node.

Then I saw this post [Is there any way to construct a transaction manually?](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/2868/is-there-any-way-to-construct-a-transaction-manually) to learn how to check my balance. They mentioned a cold wallet computer and a hot wallet computer to be safe and secure.

My question is, do i need two computers one that never goes online and one that is connected to the node? Is the method of syncing only the only-view wallet safe? Can I say my hot wallet is my view wallet?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your view wallet is hot, but that is safe. Even if someone gains access to your computer, he can not steal any funds because the view wallet doesn't store your secret spend key (which you have written on the paper backup).

Cold wallet with the spend key doesn't have to be a different computer. You could use the same physical computer, and boot from some USB Linux system to act as a safe, clean, cold machine. what's important is that you never expose the secret spend key to a potentially-compromised PC. When you're booting into a fresh Linux system which will be used only for your cold-wallet stuff and never be connected to Internet - any risk is minimized.

You could even use Windows console, but maybe it's not so user-friendly. [Here's](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/3060/how-to-create-a-cold-storage-watch-only-wallet) an exampe how to use `monero-wallet-cli` with Windows pre-install environment.